# Send touches through UIView with UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c

Basically, I want to detect pan gestures up/down in a UIView above a tableview while at the same time scroll the tableview as normal.

I've tried implementing pointInside and gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:, but they both bypass the gesture recognizer when used.

Is there a way to send the same touch to two views or to send a touch through after handling it? Or a general way to trace gestures without intercepting them?

Comment: the first question from me will be `why?`. You can trying to override the native function which is not correct. there are protocols avaible from UITableView to detect tableview scrolling.

Comment: You probably want to look at  - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer

Comment: I'm not trying to override native function, I'm trying to add more. I was thinking a UIView above the tbv to trace the touches without interfering with the tbv.

Comment: @Wasserfloh Thanks for the tip, that feels like it might work.

Comment: Do you *need* the UIView above the tableview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add you own UIPanGestureRecognizer to your Tableview.

Make them live alongside by returning YES in 
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer

i.e.

```
//setup
                        UITableView* tableview=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 500)];
                        tableview.dataSource=self;
                        [self.view addSubview:tableview];

                        UIPanGestureRecognizer* pangr=[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(someMethod:)];
                        pangr.delegate=self;
                        [tableview addGestureRecognizer:pangr];

            .
            .
            .

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{

                    return YES;
                }

 -(void)someMethod:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender{
            CGFloat velocityX = ([sender velocityInView:self.view].x);
            CGFloat velocityY = ([sender velocityInView:self.view].y);
            NSLog(@"pannig %f %f", velocityX, velocityY);
        }
```

Works fine in my Test.
If you really need the UIView above the tableview, you could just out it there and set `userInteractionEnabled=NO`

Answer (score 0):

Since the UITableView is a successor UIScrollView which reacts to self internal gestures. I think it will not be possible to implement gestures up / down in this case.